# Redirect to another web server if current page is down

Tags: iis, hosting, nameserver

I have written an application in Razor/Asp.net and I'm hosting it on our W2008R2 under IIS 7.5.

At times we will need to bring down this web server so it will be not accessible to our clients. I need a way to show that the server is under maintenance and will be back up shortly or x amount of time.

I was wondering if this would work:

add a 3rd and 4th nameserver to godaddy where we have the domain and if the iis server is not responding, would it go to the (2nd hosting site) 3rd and 4th nameservers by default?

I could put a 'server down for maintenance' on that host to catch when the server is not available.

Is the way I'm thinking this works the way it actually works?

If not, any suggestions how to direct them to another host if the current one is down for maintenance?

Comment: No, adding nameservers like that won't work.

Comment: k so it's not a rollover then. Any suggestions on a down for maintenance when the server has to be updated and such?

Comment: Drop your DNS TTL to something like 5 minutes, so you can point DNS at another server hosting a maintenance page while you do the upgrade. Or, put a proxy server in front of the main server, and have it serve an error page when the backend server is down. Or, get a load balanced pair of servers so you can drop one out of the pool, update it, and then do the same for the other.

Comment: ok great I'll look at those options that points me in the right direction.

Comment: Hey thanks for the downvote!! appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way this is done for a lot of web apps is to create a flag file when the site is in maintenance mode. A file, which is normally included in all other page files, looks for that file and either sends the user to the main site or to a "this site is in maintenance mode" type of page if the flag does exist. Simply delete the flag file to restore the system to normal operation.

Comment: this is what I ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to place a front-end web server at the edge of your network serving clients.  It will forward all requests to however many back-end web servers you have processing requests and to your clients all appears normal.

When you want to take the servers down for maintenance, you simply re-direct the front-end web server to a local static "Down for Maintenance" page, and when maintenance is over you point it back to the live servers.

A quick google search for 'iis front end' reveals several articles that should offer some assistance.